# How to send an arrays from one class to another class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have a class that has arrays inside of a method, is there any way to send these arrays into another class?

first class :

```
class getloop{
   public:
        string sendnumber;
        getloop() : sendnumber() {}
};
```

second class :

```
class runloop{
private:
    getloop a;
public:
    void showdata(){
        int b;
        std::istringstream (a.sendnumber) >> b;
        float celcius[b], reamur[b];
        for(int i=1; i<=b; i++){
            cout<<"enter celcius - "<<i<<" = ";
            cin>>celcius[i];
            reamur[i] = 0.8*celcius[i];
        }
        system("cls");
        cout<<"-----------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"|         Tabel Konversi          |"<<endl;
        cout<<"-----------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"|    Celcius    |      Reamur     |"<<endl;
        cout<<"-----------------------------------"<<endl;
        for(int i=1; i<=b; i++){
            cout<<"|"; gotoxy(8,i+4); cout<<celcius[i]<<"\370"; gotoxy(16,i+4); cout<<"|";
            gotoxy(24,i+4); cout<<reamur[i]<<"\370"; gotoxy(34,i+4); cout<<"|";
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"-----------------------------------"<<endl;
    }
    void inloop(const getloop & acceptloop){
        a = acceptloop;
    }};
```

[image: here's my code]

thank you.

Comment: Please copy your code and paste it into your SO post, so that people can copy and test it on their own system to help you with your problems.

Comment: ... moreover, so that the code becomes **searchable**.

Comment: I'm sorry I've edited my post

Comment: Flagged as unclear. In particular "is there any way to send these arrays into another class?" is unclear - did you mean object ?

Comment: I mean I want to create a new class and access an array from another class

Comment: Then what keeps you from creating that new class?

Comment: There will be a method which you call with the array as a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to make a function in Class which returns a pointer to the array. Then access the array in main() and sent it to other class.